# How to find version of Raspbmc?

Tags: raspbmc

How do I find out what is the **version** (RC3, RC5, and so on) of a **Raspbmc** installation?

There does not seem to be any version number in the XBMC GUI and neither can I seem to find this version number through command-line (using SSH).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Accoding to this [forum thread](http://forum.stmlabs.com/showthread.php?tid=3556), you can enter this from the command line (SSH)

```
cat /scripts/upd_hist/build_info
```